# How can I easily develop an app such that it will run on every major OS?

Tags: frameworks, cross-platform, project

Everything that I have coded upto this point has been launched from Command Prompt or the IDE itself. I would like the ability to deploy an application such that launching it doesn't require a tutorial for novices. .exe, .apk, .app, ELF. Double-click and go.

I recall creating .exe files from Python as being restrictivly difficult. I was thinking C# and found .net/maui. It doesn't support linux, which I could maybe look past, but it also doesn't appear to support creating .exe files.

Java is more low level than I would like to deal with. Learning a new language that runs virtually could be the solution. I havn't done much investigating as this wouldn't be the ideal. (Edit: JVM requires an additional install, so that's not going to work.)

I don't have any experience with web developement, but it seems like a promising route none the less. It is not clear to me if I can create a local icon-launchable webpage that will run an application in your browser sans-server. Additionally, I am not sure how far my known languages will take me before I have to then learn CSS or whatever.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) seems to be popular choice for cross-platform development in case you don't mind developing with JavaScript.

[QT](https://www.qt.io/) is another cross-platform framework that was around for a long time.

Specifically for .NET, there's [MAUI](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/maui) (mobile-focused, no Linux), [Avalonia UI](https://www.avaloniaui.net/), [Eto Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto), [AlterNET UI](https://www.alternet-ui.com/). The last one is desktop-only and still in beta.